# SearchBar deep search into JSON

Tags: json, angular, firebase, ionic2

I'm implementing a searchbar in IONIC 2 that search a JSON in one view so it can send its details to another view.

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "Alphaville I": { //FIRST KEY
    "ida": [{ //SECOND KEYS
      "hora": "05:40",
      "local": "AV. FERNÃO DIAS PAES LEME (Pref. Várzea Paulista)"
    },... ],
    "volta": [{ //SECOND KEYS
      "hora": "05:40",
      "local": "AV. FERNÃO DIAS PAES LEME (Pref. Várzea Paulista)"
    },... ]
  }, ... //MULTIPLE ITENS
}
```

So, in one view i create a list with the first keys (like `Alphaville I`), but i need to search the `local` inside of it.

But the Angular 2 *ngFor requires an array, so i iterate through my object and push it to an array, doing this it excludes my first key, so what i'm doing now (without searching, of course) is saving the keys in one array, geting the index and passing the `jsonResultExample[index]` to another page.

i'm using the basic searchbar example like the one in [Seachbar Component Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar).

So what i need is: Search by the `local` key and return the first key (`Alphaville I`) of the nodes the contain the input text, the same `local` can appear in other first keys.

How can i do this? I can't post a better code because i haven't tried anything.

Is there a better way to structure my JSON for this? (i'm using firebase btw);

Any help or ideas is welcome, thanks.

### EDIT

So i saved the first key value along with `ida` and `volta` so i can simply iterate through it, get the key value and everything without many problems, but since i need to filter by `local` it appears inside `ida`and `volta` as another array (cause i have many of these values), so it's looking like this now:

[image: My Object]

So now how can i access the `local`? Is it better to create another object only with all `local` and a key for every `linha` so i can return the values?

Remembering this is the searchbar code for Ionic 2 and my JSON has over 4k lines:

```
getItems(ev: any) {
  // Reset items back to all of the items
  this.initializeItems();

  // set val to the value of the searchbar
  let val = ev.target.value;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
      return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I were you, I would have created a Map<String,String[]> which maps local to list of First Keys, assuming there is a one to many relationship. How you create a map depends on reliability of your json format. You could write a generic function which loops through every property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes to personal experience on how to design data structure. Therefore I can't say the follow method is the best way.

First, in the case that we have complicated data structure, I don't prefer using map (a.k.a. object as data structure) in javascript. The main reason is pretty related to what you are facing, object by design cannot be iterated. Yes you can use `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` but they are so ugly and hard to fit on every cases.

It is a nice move to put your first key as a property. That comes to the second problem. There seems to be an assumption in your structure that, one `linha` is mapped only to one `local` or one `local` is only related to one `linha`. If so, I suggest building another separated map only for the `linha` and `local` relationship.

Another approach is to normalize your data structure in to multiple separated javascript objects like what you do on database. By doing so, you can maximize the data flexibility that you can query whatever you want by `Array.prototype.filter()`, `Array.prototype.map()` or even directly access by its index. However, this approach may increase the lines of code as you need to manage multiple maps.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the only plausible solution is having a second map. This also helped me in other cases, since searching a biiiiiiiiig object was taking me almost 2secs and now it takes only 0.3sec. So thanks again